# Windows 8 Metro App (Grid Application) transition with black flickering

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, microsoft-metro

I'm building a Windows 8 Metro App based on the Grid Application template.
Everything was going smoothly until I tried to change the Theme and Background of the App.

I applied an Image Background to all 3 XAML Page's Grid. Also, I changed the Theme to "Light" in the Application Package Manifest, but it didn't do anything.

After searching I found a solution, setting RequestedTheme="Light" in the App.xaml

Now, I have a Light themed Application with the background I want, but every time I navigate to a diferente Page it has a black flicker. It seems the transition still has the Black Theme.

Is that the problem? How do I change that?

Thanks

Comment: Just in case someone is still gonna read this... The problem seemed to be the Visual Studio 11.
I Changed to Visual Studio 2012, made the required modifications to the project and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 2):

In App.xaml.cs, set the background property of the app's root frame. You can do it in the overridden OnLaunch method, just before navigation to the initial page.

> rootFrame.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White); //whatever color